# Error while capturing a video with pose trainer repo that based on openpose repo

Tags: python, caffe, video-capture, openpose

While i am running this : https://github.com/stevenzchen/pose-trainer/blob/master/README.md
this repo extract the pose estimator from openpose repo : https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

it gives me an error 
and i dont know where the problem is ? 
is it in the first or second repo ?
the error is :

```
$ python main.py --video videos\curls.mp4

Error:
VideoCapture (IP camera/video) could not be opened for path: '..\videoscurls.mp4'. If it is a video path, is the path correct?


Coming from:
- D:\Users\Gines\Desktop\openpose-master\openpose-1.3.0\src\openpose\producer\vi                         deoCaptureReader.cpp:op::VideoCaptureReader::VideoCaptureReader():37
- D:\Users\Gines\Desktop\openpose-master\openpose-1.3.0\src\openpose\producer\vi                         deoCaptureReader.cpp:op::VideoCaptureReader::VideoCaptureReader():41
- D:\Users\Gines\Desktop\openpose-master\openpose-1.3.0\src\openpose\utilities\f                         lagsToOpenPose.cpp:op::flagsToProducer():203
C:\Users\BioHelwan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2957: R                         untimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  out=out, **kwargs)
C:\Users\BioHelwan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:80: Runtim                         eWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
processing video file...
Exercise arm detected as: left.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 53, in main
    (correct, feedback) = evaluate_pose(pose_seq, args.exercise)
  File "D:\Got\after first discussion\Main\pose-trainer-master\evaluate.py", lin                         e 18, in evaluate_pose
    return _bicep_curl(pose_seq)
  File "D:\Got\after first discussion\Main\pose-trainer-master\evaluate.py", lin                         e 55, in _bicep_curl
    upper_arm_vecs = upper_arm_vecs / np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(upper_arm_ve                         cs, axis=1), axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\BioHelwan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py",                          line 2287, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Unix-based pieces of software do not run well with backslashes. Try:

```
python main.py --video videos/curls.mp4
```

Or sometimes the following also works:

```
python main.py --video videos\\curls.mp4
```